# How do I get a specific word in a theorem enviroment to be in non italics

Tags: fonts

I want a specific word in a definition to be non italics. I want to define a function on the qcs font, but inside the definition enviroment, it's written in italics no matter what I do. I didn't manage to find a solution anywhere.

Any help is appreciated. Here's my attempt

```
\newcommand{\ex}{{\fontfamily{qcs}\selectfont ex}}
```

And the definition goes like

```
\begin{deff}[Número de Turán] Sea $H$ un grafo arbitrario. Definimos el 
número de Turán de $H$ (también llamado el número extremal de $H$) como
$$\ex(n,H):=\max\{e(G):H\not\subset G\subset K_n\}$$
vale decir, la máxima cantidad de aristas que puede tener un grafo $H$- 
libre de $n$ vértices
\end{deff}
```

Comment: No example, but does `\emph{text}` work?

Comment: Can you please show your attempts?

Comment: @egreg Just added it to the question

Comment: @mickep It worked! Can I make it a specific font though?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do font changes like that in math mode.

And no, `\emph` is not the answer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathqcs}{OT1}{qcs}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathOperator{\ex}{\mathqcs{ex}}

\newtheorem{deff}{Definición}

\begin{document}

\begin{deff}[Número de Turán] Sea $H$ un grafo arbitrario. Definimos el 
número de Turán de $H$ (también llamado el número extremal de $H$) como
\[
\ex(n,H):=\max\{e(G):H\not\subset G\subset K_n\}
\]
vale decir, la máxima cantidad de aristas que puede tener un grafo 
$H$-libre de $n$ vértices
\end{deff}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'm not sure what's the role of Century Schoolbook in this context, though.

Avoid `$$` in LaTeX.